# How to use Ratchet to respond to HTML5 server-side events?

Tags: php, websocket, ratchet

(Note: I've intentionally put non adequate `websocket` tag here, as it's best chance for WebSocket expert folks to know architecture of Ratchet).

I'm up for implementing HTML5 server side events, and what I need is server side solution. Since hanging Apache's one process per connection (connection pool limit, memory consumption...) is out of consideration I was hoping that **Ratchet project** can be of help, since it's most maintained project and they have `http` server coupled along with other components.

My question is: how can I use it? Not for upgrading `http` request (default usage), but for serving dynamically generated content.

**What have I tried so far?**

1. installed `Ratchet` as explained in tutorial
2. tested WebSocket functionality - works properly
3. followed very basic set of instructions [given on page that describes `http` server component](http://socketo.me/docs/http):

`/bin/http-server.php`

```
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
    $http = new HttpServer(new MyWebPage);

$server = IoServer::factory($http);
$server->run();
```

One should not be an expert to figure out that `MyWebPage` class here needs to be declared in order for server to work, but how?

The Ratchet documentation does not seems to cover this.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @Andy unfortunately no.

Comment: I played around with this all day yesterday and have a basic working HTTP server now. I'll post an answer over the next few days once I've tidied everything up a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `MyWebPage` class needs to implement `HttpServerInterface`. Since it's just going to be a simple request/response you need to send a response and then close the connection within the `onOpen()` method of your class:

```
<?php

use Guzzle\Http\Message\RequestInterface;
use Guzzle\Http\Message\Response;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServerInterface;

class MyWebPage implements HttpServerInterface
{
    protected $response;

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn, RequestInterface $request = null)
    {
        $this->response = new Response(200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        ]);

        $this->response->setBody('Hello World!');

        $this->close($conn);
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
    {
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg)
    {
    }

    protected function close(ConnectionInterface $conn)
    {
        $conn->send($this->response);
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

I ended up using the `Ratchet\App` class instead of `Ratchet\Http\HttpServer` because it allows you to set up routing among other things, so your `/bin/http-server.php` would then look like this:

```
<?php

use Ratchet\App;

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new App('localhost', 8080, '127.0.0.1');
$app->route('/', new MyWebPage(), ['*']);

$app->run();
```

When you run `php bin/http-server.php` and visit http://localhost:8080 you should see the Hello World! response in your browser.

This is all you need for a basic request/response system, but it could be extended further by implementing HTML templates and things like that. I've implemented this myself in a little [test project](https://github.com/andyexeter/ratchet-http-server) which I've uploaded to github along with a lot of other things, including an abstract controller which I can extend for different pages.

Comment: Seems like just what I'm looking for - thank you for your effort. I'll accept your answer right after I get to test your code - upvote so far.

Comment: @Miloshio The Github project contains a lot more functionality than this answer too - it can serve HTML templates instead of just a basic plain text response. There's a few other things like a config object for getting and setting configuration values and also a logger :) The [HomeController](https://github.com/andyexeter/ratchet-http-server/blob/master/src/Palmtree/RatchetWebServer/Controller/HomeController.php) shows how to use the request object.

Comment: Yes, that's fully functional http server. Now it's up to me to implement `Content-Type: text/event-stream` and pulsing updates. Thank you so much. I'll fork your project on Github.

Answer (score -1):

[Chat server using Ratchet - Basic](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgiqzl4BEJTMftek4tAEJ0atjp90LwlIC)

[Chat server using Ratchet - Advanced](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgiqzl4BEJTOiJolWtRF2tEhlkX1r-s5a)

Check the link above. The guy here is using Ratchet to build a real time chat server. He is basically storing `usernames` initially and then sending/broadcasting to all. You can modify it and check at the time of sending that certain `username` or `uid` is active at the moment and send data to them only. You can generate data dynamically and send to particular users or to all. May be this will help.